# Mongo - Distinct match entire array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents that look like this:

```
{"arr":["a","b","c"]},
{"arr":["a","b","x"]},
{"arr":["c","b","a"]},
{"arr":["a","b","c"]}
```

I want to call distinct to get all unique arrays, however, querying for an array matches elements by default, meaning this:

```
db.getCollection("mycoll").distinct("arr",{});
```

returns:

```
["a","b","c","x"]
```

instead of

```
[["a","b","c"],
 ["a","b","x"],
 ["c","b","a"]]
```

How can I query for distinct arrays? Optionally, I'd love to get the number of occurrences of each result too:

```
{["a","b","c"] : 2,
 ["a","b","x"] : 1,
 ["c","b","a"] : 1}
```

Comment: Use `$group` on array with `$sum` in aggregate pipeline. Something like `db.collectionname.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$arr", count:{$sum:1}}})`

Comment: This worked for me: `db.mycoll.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$arr",count:{$sum:1}}})`. Thank you! If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by sum mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909694/group-by-sum-mongodb)

Comment: The answer is the same, but I'd argue it isn't a duplicate. My question was fundamentally about distinct not working on array fields. That question has nothing to do with distinct or array fields.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from , but the reason I marked it as duplicate as in aggregation's $group (distinct), it doesn't matter what is type of the field.

Comment: I realize that. I still believe the question is different, even though the answer is the same. Someone searching for how to use distinct on a array field would not have found that answer, unless they already knew to use aggregation. The count was only tangentially related to the primary problem I was encountering.

Comment: Makes sense. I have retracted the close vote and added answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$group` by `arr` with `$sum` in aggregation pipeline.

```
 db.mycoll.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$arr", count:{$sum:1}}})
```