# How to write aggregate function of mongo for the following condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongo, which consists of approx half a million documents, and from that i want a sum of a specific field with specific ids.

**For example :**

a single document has a field of meter_id and total power.
So i want to seperate documents having same meter ids and then calculate the total power for each collection having same meter id.

example document:

```
_id:5e444fc1c5e86c84d1044aeb
meter_id:"jhk"
date:2017-06-17T18:39:28.795+00:00
activePower:Object
unit:"kwh"
Active Power L1:"0"
Active Power L2:"0"
Active Power L3:"0"
Total Active Power:"5"
reactivePower:Object
apparentPower:Object
frequency:Object
thd:Object
```

now i have to group by meter ids and want the total of total active power field which is a key-value for active power object

expected output:

```
{ _id: 'jhk', total: 69236, totalAmount:  }
```

Comment: Show what have you tried so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by sum mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909694/group-by-sum-mongodb)

Comment: @Dharmik soni : Voting to close it as the above link provides you what you're looking for..

Comment: No, it doesnt, it just count the number of documents with same parameter.
But i want to get the total sum of other parameters as well

Comment: Can you update the question with sample documents and describe the expected output? Currently your question is not clear, put some effort to your question if you want to get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group :{_id : '$meter_id', total : {$sum : { $toInt : '$activePower.TotalActivePower'}}}}])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ItXibVSd__I)

**Note :** It seems like your `$activePower.TotalActivePower` field is a string, if it is then we need to use `$toInt` to convert it into number in order to calculate the sum across all documents matching to an `_id` criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the help